# GSAP slider not working in IE11 and safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, internet-explorer-11, gsap

I integrated this slider into my website after I find that it is not working on IE11 and safari :

Here is a link to the slider's code :

https://codepen.io/gvrban/pen/qjbpaa

IT works fine in Chrome and in IE11 I have tried changing the style but the problem persist. I think it is related to the flexbox.

HTML part (only one slide ):

```
<div class="slider">
<div class="slider-wrapper flex">
        <div class="slide flex">
        <div class="slide-image slider-link next"><img src="https://goranvrban.com/codepen/img6.jpg"><div class="overlay"></div></div>
        <div class="slide-content">
            <div class="slide-date">30.10.2017.</div>
            <div class="slide-title">LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SITE MATE, AD EST ABHORREANT</div>
            <div class="slide-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad est abhorreant efficiantur, vero oporteat apeirian in vel. Et appareat electram appellantur est. Ei nec duis invenire. Cu mel ipsum laoreet, per rebum omittam ex. </div>
            <div class="slide-more">READ MORE</div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
<div class="arrows">
<a href="#" title="Previous" class="arrow slider-link prev"></a>
<a href="#" title="Next" class="arrow slider-link next"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS part:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
body {background-color: #0D1B2B; overflow-x: hidden; font-family: roboto; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; margin: 0;}
.flex { display: -webkit-flex; display: flex; -webkit-flex-direction: row;  flex-direction: row; -webkit-justify-content: flex-start; justify-content: flex-start;}

.slider-wrapper div {position: relative;}
.slider-wrapper {margin-top: 5vw;  margin-left: 11vw;}
.slide-image {height: 24vw;}
.slide-image img {width: 24vw; cursor: pointer;}
.slide-content {width: 25vw; color: #fff; padding:3vw 18vw 3vw 9vw;}
.slide-date {color: #0a8acb; font-size: 1.1vw; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: 0.1vw; padding-bottom: 1.4vw;}
.slide-title {font-size: 1.2vw; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: 0.1vw; line-height: 1.55vw; padding-bottom: 1.8vw;}
.slide-text {font-size: 0.80vw; line-height: 1.2vw; opacity: 0.8; padding-bottom: 4vw;}
.slide-more {font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: 0.1vw; float: left; font-size: 0.9vw;}
.slide-bullet {width: 0.5vw; height: 0.5vw; background-color: #0b8bcc; border-radius: 200%; position: relative; margin-left: 1.2vw;}
.slide-nav {margin-left: 64vw; margin-top: -5.5vw;}

div.overlay-blue {width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; transition: 0.5s ease all;}
div.overlay-blue:hover {background-color: rgba(13, 27, 43, 0.5);}

.arrows{width: 3.5vw; margin-top: -5.8vw; margin-left: 72vw; position: relative;}
.arrow {display: inline-block; position: absolute; width: 1.2vw; height: 1.2vw; background: transparent; text-indent: -9999px; border-top: 0.15vw solid #fff; border-left: 0.15vw solid #fff; transition: all .1s ease-in-out; text-decoration: none; color: transparent;
}
.arrow:hover {border-color: #0A8ACB; border-width: 0.25vw;
}
.arrow:before {display: block; height: 200%; width: 200%; margin-left: -50%; margin-top: -50%; content: ""; transform: rotate(45deg);}
.arrow.prev {transform: rotate(-45deg); left: 0;}
.arrow.next {transform: rotate(135deg); right: 0;}
```

JS part:

```
( function($) {

  $(document).ready(function() {

    var s           = $('.slider'),
        sWrapper    = s.find('.slider-wrapper'),
        sItem       = s.find('.slide'),
        btn         = s.find('.slider-link'),
        sWidth      = sItem.width(),
        sCount      = sItem.length,
        slide_date  = s.find('.slide-date'),
        slide_title = s.find('.slide-title'),
        slide_text  = s.find('.slide-text'),
        slide_more  = s.find('.slide-more'),
        slide_image = s.find('.slide-image img'),
        sTotalWidth = sCount * sWidth;

    sWrapper.css('width', sTotalWidth);
    sWrapper.css('width', sTotalWidth);

    var clickCount  = 0;

    btn.on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      if( $(this).hasClass('next') ) {

        ( clickCount < ( sCount - 1 ) ) ? clickCount++ : clickCount = 0;
      } else if ( $(this).hasClass('prev') ) {

        ( clickCount > 0 ) ? clickCount-- : ( clickCount = sCount - 1 );
      }
      TweenMax.to(sWrapper, 0.4, {x: '-' + ( sWidth * clickCount ) })


      //CONTENT ANIMATIONS

      var fromProperties = {autoAlpha:0, x:'-50', y:'-10'};
      var toProperties = {autoAlpha:0.8, x:'0', y:'0'};

      TweenLite.fromTo(slide_image, 1, {autoAlpha:0, y:'40'}, {autoAlpha:1, y:'0'});
      TweenLite.fromTo(slide_date, 0.4, fromProperties, toProperties);
      TweenLite.fromTo(slide_title, 0.6, fromProperties, toProperties);
      TweenLite.fromTo(slide_text, 0.8, fromProperties, toProperties);
      TweenLite.fromTo(slide_more, 1, fromProperties, toProperties);

    });

  });
})(jQuery);

$('.overlay').addClass('overlay-blue');
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Good morning,

you can console.log(sWidth, 'sWidth') under your variables declaration and see that your variable don't return the same value in different browsers.

The solution :

remove flex class from your slide html code and change the display to block to get the same calculation cross browsers and you should add another div inside it to keep your flex style.

change your HTML slide code to :

```
 <div class="slide">
      <div class="slide-container">
      <div class="slide-image slider-link prev"><img src="https://goranvrban.com/codepen/img2.jpg">
              <div class="overlay"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slide-content">
               <div class="slide-content-inner">
              <div class="slide-date">30.07.2017.</div>
              <div class="slide-title">LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SITE MATE, AD EST ABHORREANT</div>
              <div class="slide-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad est abhorreant efficiantur, vero oporteat apeirian in
                vel. Et appareat electram appellantur est. Ei nec duis invenire. Cu mel ipsum laoreet, per rebum omittam ex.
              </div>
          <div class="slide-more">READ MORE</div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and add these css styles :

```
.slide {
  display:block;
}

.slide-container{
  display: flex;
}
.slide-content-inner{
  width:35vw;
  padding: 5%;
}
```

And change these (remove the padding and change width) :

```
.slide-content {
   width: 50vw;  //changed to 50vw
   color: #fff; 
   /*padding:3vw 18vw 3vw 9vw;*/ //removed
}
```

You get the solution with extra styling :)